# Laravel | Filter null values from an associative array

Tags: laravel, associative-array

I have an associative array like this:

```
 $myarray = array(
                'key1' => 'value1'
                'key2' => 'value1','value2','value3', null ,'value4'
                 null
                'key4' => null ,'value2','value3', null
                'key5'
                 null
                );
```

I want to remove the null values and I tried this:

```
$collection = collect($myarray);

            $filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
                return $value != null;
            });
```

The result is this:

```
     $myarray = array(
                'key1' => 'value1'
                'key2' => 'value1','value2','value3', null ,'value4'
                'key4' => null ,'value2','value3', null
                'key5'
                );
```

But my desired result is like this:

```
     $myarray = array(
                'key1' => 'value1'
                'key2' => 'value1','value2','value3','value4'
                 null
                'key4' => 'value2','value3'
                'key5'
                 null
                );
```

How can I do this?

PS: I'm using Laravel 5.4.36

Comment: Can't confirm. The result would be a collection. Even if you do `$filtered->all();`, the result is `[
  "key1" => "value1"
  "key2" => "value1"
  0 => "value2"
  1 => "value3"
  3 => "value4"
  5 => "value2"
  6 => "value3"
  8 => "key5"
]`

Comment: I did an array_push and view the JSON on chrome developer tools . That was my result from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code removes `null` values from the top-level array. Your "desired result" removes `null` values from the *nested* arrays.

Try this instead:

```php
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    if (is_null($key) || !is_array($value)) {
        continue;
    }

    $myarray[$key] = array_filter($value);
}
```

Comment: This does work, well explained and concise. Thanks a lot!